# How to filter Data in Firebase v9

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, data-structures, filtering

Hey guys I have a question about how to search/filter data in Firestore and React js would be nice if someone could help.

So let me describe my problem.

First I have created a collection called firearms which contains documents
with the user.uid as well .

And in this document I created a subcollection with auto-generated documents they all have two values the name of the firearm and the name of the manufacturer.

That means if a user has two firearms he stores two documents in the subcollection  for each firearm one  document.

// `firearms/auth.currentUser.uid/firearmssubcollection/auto-IDs`

Field values [ name , manufacturer ]

My goal is it to display the ( manufacturer ) from the collection 'firearms' to other users after they search for a specific gun .

If I search with autocomplete lets say for
Baretta
I receive all the Baretta Pistols from the current logged in User but I need the Baretta Pistols from all Users and not just the one from the logged in user.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import { collection, query, where, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore"
import { db, auth } from '../firebaseConfig';
import Autocomplete from '@mui/material/Autocomplete';


 function Suche() {

  
  const [kurzHersteller, setKurzHersteller] = useState();
  const kurzHerstellerArray = [ 'Andere','Baretta', 'Walther', 'Haenal']

 

  const handleClick = async () => {


    const kurzRef = collection(db, `kurzwaffen/${auth.currentUser.uid}/kurzwaffensub`);

    const q = query(kurzRef, where("kurzHersteller", "==", `${kurzHersteller}`));
  

    

  const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
  // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
  console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
  });


      
}

  return (

<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    <Box sx={{ marginLeft: {lg:'15vw', md:'0vw', sm:'0vw', xs:'0vw'}, padding:{lg:4 ,md:4 ,sm:4 , xs:0}, paddingBottom:{lg:2, md:15, sm:10, xs:10}}}>
     <Grid container spacing={7} alignItems='center' justifyContent='center' >

        <Grid item >
           <Card className='CardSuche' sx={{ maxWidth: 700 , height: {lg: 900, md: 900, sm: 750, xs: 750}, backgroundColor:'rgba(39, 39, 39, 0.35)', backdropFilter:'blur(6px)', boxShadow:'0 8px 32px 0 rgba(107, 107, 107, 0.37)' }}>
              <CardMedia
                 component="img"
                 sx={{height: {lg: 500, md: 500, sm:340 , xs: 340}}}
                 image="../images/1911.jpg" 
          />

        <Grid container direction='column' spacing={1}>

          <CardContent>
                    
             < Grid item>
                 <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="div" color='white'>
                    Kurzwaffen
                 </Typography>
             </Grid>

             < Grid item >
                    <Typography variant="body2" color="text.secondary">
                        <Grid container direction='column' justifyContent='center' alignItems='center' spacing={2}>

                          <Grid item >
                            <Paper sx={{width:{lg:550 , md:550 ,sm:360, xs:360}, height: 70 }}>
                            <Autocomplete
                               disablePortal
                               id="combo-box-demo"
                               options={kurzHerstellerArray}
      
                               value={kurzHersteller}
                               onChange={(_event,value) => setKurzHersteller(value)}
      
                              sx={{ width: 300 }}
                              renderInput={(params) => 
                              <TextField {...params} label="Hersteller"/>}
    />
                            </Paper>
                          </Grid>

                          

                        </Grid>
                    </Typography>
             </Grid>
           </Box>

export default Suche;
```

```
 match /kurzwaffen/{userId}/kurzwaffensub/{waffenID} {
      allow write, delete: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId;
      allow read: if request.auth != null;
    }
```

Here are my security rules for this collection.

Hope you can tell me what I have to change to receive all the weapons instead of only the weapons from the currently logged in user .

Im to dumb to find my mistake ^^.

Comment: The Firebase documentation on queries is up to date: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries Outside of that, it's more likely someone can help if you show the [minimal code that reproduces where you are stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I hope now its clear what I meant ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to search across all `kurzwaffensub` (sub)collections in the database, you can use a [collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) to do so.

```
const kurzRef = collectionGroup(db, 'kurzwaffensub');
```

Comment: Thanks for helping but unfortunalty another error occured. I made a comment perhabs your able to understand me better because I know its hard to answer a question if its not well formulated. Im sorry about that :D

Comment: Oops, that was a mistake from me. You should only send the collection name, not an entire path. I updated the code in my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much  now its working.:)